# Where to find locahost:port location

Tags: html, localhost, port

I have a product which makes webpages. I can see the preview of the modified site by browsing to the following address using a web browser

http://localhost:9094/

I realize that , the created html files are on my localsystem, yet I was unable to find where it is?. Is there any trick to findout the physical folder location  from this url??

Comment: How are you deploying/hosting this?

Answer (score 0):

> I realize that , the created html files are on my localsystem

**Maybe**. They might also be generated on demand in response to the request.

> Is there any trick to findout the physical folder location from this url??

Searching the disk for files and directories which match parts of the URL **might** work, but there is no need for a URL to map onto a directory structure (or even a file) at all.

Comment: I am using an offline system thats why I told that all files are in may be in localsystem. Ofcourse, it might be generated on demand in response to my request. Searched many times, but not found any result....!

Answer (score 0):

They could be either files in your harddisk or dynamic webpages.

What you can do is to investigate which is the daemon listening on that port.

```
netstat -ptuna | grep 9094
```

Should give you information about the process name and PID. Then with this information you can query what are the files this process is using. The `lsof`command can be helpful for this task.

Comment: I am using a windows 8 machine. I pasted your command in DOS shell but it giving following message, " 'grep’ is not recognized as an internal or external command operable pran or batch file". Kindly point out my mistake.

Comment: Sorry Praveen, those commands are for Linux. Probably you can find equivalent for Windows....